# How to loop through TextBox controls? (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, controls

I have 49 text boxes that are on a form in a table-like format. Each row of textboxes belongs to a different category. I'm wondering how would I cycle through them all in an array?

**Here's what I mean:**

*txtName(0).Text

txtOtherName(0).Text

txtName(1).Text

txtOtherName(1).Text*

((and so on...))
Where (#) is a unique suffix of the textbox name.

I'm trying to avoid assigning them all separate variables (in each group) if possible. So I would have a total of 7 variables and 49 textboxes.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is no # in your question

Comment: @VahidK. The (#) represents the number inside the parentheses in the textbox name. The parentheses & number are just a placeholder to get the general idea of what I mean in my question.

Comment: _I have 49 text boxes that are on a form in a table-like format._ Seems like bad design which produce thats kind of problems. Consider using `DataGridView` control if it is possible in your case

Comment: @Fabio it's for a project for school. The text boxes are necessary for it (sadly). I am using a `DataGridView` to display the information back to the user though. But yes, as bad as a design as it may seem, the textboxes are needed. I've tried to make it as decent looking as possible, which it actually doesn't look too too bad. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can traverse through each control this way

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    var textBox = control as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
          // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Right idea, but two problems. First, the array should be one of Controls(), not TextBoxes. You don't know they're all TextBoxes yet, you check that later when you're looping with the `As` operator. Second, the question is tagged [c#], so it might be more appropriate to post sample code in that language. (Not that VB.NET isn't trivially translatable to C#, but this person is probably a beginner and may not be able to do that yet.)

Comment: Agreed @CodyGray, My mistake. I approved an edit with C#.

Comment: if (control is TextBox) before assuming it is one

Comment: @Hemal so, this.Controls is referring to all of the textboxes on the form?

Comment: Controls means all controls including textboxes. Then casting is done for a single control into Textbox. If its successfully casted as Textbox, then it wont be null, and then you can go ahead.

Comment: @Hemal I understand how the loop works, but I'm just not getting how I use it efficiently to minimize my code instead of declaring an unnecessary amount of variables for the textboxes. Arrays/Looping and such are not one of my strengths. (Fairly new programmer, if you haven't noticed haha).

Comment: Agreed on your side but this is the least amount of code as I understand and provided by @VahidK.

Comment: Oh right, my mistake haha. @Vahid K. any help with the issue above? I failed to notice you provided the code.

Comment: @RunningEXE No problem. I do not think there is a way to reduce that code. You could write it with .ToList().Foreach ... but will not help performance.

Comment: That would be: Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(x => { // do your stuff here });

Comment: @Vahid K. Ah, thanks! Now i know that it's not entirely possible to minimize such code.

Answer (score 0):

This may help: `root` is the container or window, `id` is the control:

```
#region Find Control Recursive
public Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
       return root;
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
        if (t != null)
           return t;
    }
    return null;
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Why would you do that?! Your simple foreach loop does all the work. Then why all the overheads of recursive calls?!